# Lightweight alternative to jQuery for class / id selecting

Tags: jquery, dom, css-selectors

Let's say I want to build a non-dependent javascript framework/script. Is there a way to utilize jQuery's amazing class and element selecting functionality

```
$('.this') or $('#this') or $('div', '.this')
```

Without being dependent on jQuery or using jQuery if it is available but if not, it works without it? I have searched this high and low. Maybe I am searching incorrectly as the closest I have gotten is this:

[Selecting elements without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266631/selecting-elements-without-jquery/7266732#7266732)

However, that is not as in-depth as I want or as similar as I want to jQuery. I have thought about digging through jQuery source and gutting that piece out and using it, but I hope someone has already done this and I am just looking in the wrong place and someone else knows about it.

**Update**

This has been answered in a few ways, and thank you to the quick replies. I was searching in the wrong method. I finally came on: https://github.com/ded/qwery

However this answer here does the job perfectly:
[Lightweight alternative to jQuery for class / id selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749146/lightweight-alternative-to-jquery-for-class-id-selecting/7749179#7749179)

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just use jQuery?  Until functionality like this is built into browsers in a standard way (HAH!), you're stuck with using utility libraries like jQuery.

Comment: It's for a script where you aren't needed to rely on jQuery, but can use it if available. Not everyone uses jQuery and I would like to tap into that source and before I go code my own, I was hoping there is already something made like this.

Comment: If you really need to make the app lightweight, then don't use a gutted jQuery. Go search the web for a framework that is designed only for dom navigation and manipulation. There are dozens of frameworks out there, I'm sure there's one that fits your needs closely.

Comment: The `id` selector is easy enough: `document.getElementById('#id`)`. So far not as well supported, but [document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), which will return a list.

Comment: Don't be so pessimistic SoWeLie.  This functionality is available to about 70% of internet users though document.querySelectorAll.  Only IE6 and IE7 don't have it and you could polyfill back to something like jQuery in that case.

Comment: Queries were never needed in the first place. Clever DOM traversal (try to think recursive) along with some RegExp checks on an element's `className` can get the job done. Rely mostly on `id`s if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In everything but IE6 and IE7, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` or `someElement.querySelectorAll` to perform similar selection functionality.

**Update** more details:

It looks like ZeptoJS does the following.  This uses quick functions for `$$(document, '#myid')`, `$$(document, '.myclass')`, `$$(document, 'div')` and slow searches for `$$(document, 'div > .myclass')`

```
var classSelectorRE = /^\.([\w-]+)$/,
    idSelectorRE = /^#([\w-]+)$/,
    tagSelectorRE = /^[\w-]+$/;

$$ = function(element, selector){
  var found;
  return (element === document && idSelectorRE.test(selector)) ?
    ( (found = element.getElementById(RegExp.$1)) ? [found] : [] ) :
    Array.prototype.slice.call(
      classSelectorRE.test(selector) ? element.getElementsByClassName(RegExp.$1) :
      tagSelectorRE.test(selector) ? element.getElementsByTagName(selector) :
      element.querySelectorAll(selector)
    );
}
```

Comment: There is however a syntax issue, before `slice.call` you are missing `[].`

Comment: That's true.  This was a cut and paste.  Zepto defined `emptyArray = [], slice = emptyArray.slice`. I will update the code above.

Comment: Is this a performance thing or why isn't querySelectorAll used in all cases?

Answer (score 14):

You could do what jQuery does and use Sizzle: http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 13):

The answer to "I need a small JS library that..." is this site: http://microjs.com/

specifically, you're looking for a selector engine:

http://microjs.com/#css

Comment: Nice collection, neatly organized by microjs.com. Not sure why they don't include Sizzle (smaller than some on microjs) but certainly a bunch of worthy options!

Comment: I found Qwery, which I know is on there and it does the job and is smaller than Sizzle. Thanks for the suggestion however @GregPettit

Comment: My pleasure. Be sure to 'accept' DA's answer as it was the most helpful to you. :)

Comment: It was before Brian posted his which is the smallest and fastest implementation, and works for what I need.

Comment: That *is* odd that sizzle isn't on the list. I want to say I saw it on there before...

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/)? You'd still be dependent on a framework, but it's much lighter weight: about 5kb instead of 31kb.

Answer (score 2):

Just try [jBone](http://jbone.js.org/), library for Events and DOM manipulation. jBone has much better performance then jQuery/Zepto, smaller size and full support for all selectors, events API's.

Answer (score 1):

[MicroSelector](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/micro-selector). Even smaller and faster than Zepto, which is smaller than Sizzle, which is smaller than JQuery.