# I want to auto click

Tags: javascript

I want to auto click on this link on a website.

```
<a href="/wall/withdraw.php?processor=ppp">Withdraw</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by auto click

Comment: I mean when a page load contain this link, code will click auto on this link, and proceed further to next page?

Comment: I want a code like this : setTimeout(function() { document.evaluate("//input[@value='Submit Now' and @type='submit' and contains(@class, 'button')]", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click(); }, 2000); that will work with it?  thanks in advance dear!

Comment: IIRC, you cannot click on a link programmatically. But you can read the href attribute, and use `window.location.replace` method to load the URL.

Comment: @ bvukelic thank, I'm noob, can you please tell me how to add code of window.location.replace with auto clcik code?

Answer (score 1):

You can fire it's `click()` method.

```
<a href="/wallet/withdraw.php?processor=ppp" id="foo">Withdraw</a>

document.getElementById("foo").click();
```

You'll need some way to select the element, I gave it an ID and used `getElementById()`

Comment: but I'm not able to edit or add an id in this code, because, this code is not in my site, I just want to click on it, code will click auto on this link, and proceed further to next page?

Comment: I want a code like this : setTimeout(function() {
    document.evaluate("//input[@value='Submit Now' and @type='submit' and contains(@class, 'button')]", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click();
}, 2000); that will work with it?

Comment: and thanks for your answer, but its not work for me?

Comment: @Umer you'll have to be more specific than "doesn't work"

Comment: thanks very much, dear I'm very noob in coding, I just want to auto click on a html link, and I'm not able to add ID in that link, because I'm not the owner of that site. thanks again bro.

Comment: You'll need a way to select the element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266631/selecting-elements-without-jquery for other ways of selecting elements.

Comment: ok, thank for your help, I will try something other. Peace!